# How do I remove the div `col-right sidebar` from the default theme html?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd, html

I want to completely remove the div `col-right sidebar` from the default magento 1.9 theme.

I've tried creating a `local.xml` file containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
      <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

But this only removes the content of the div. I want to completely remove it from the html code so the page can contain more products on a single page.

Now:

[image]

Goal:

[image]

What should I try next?

Comment: What does this element have to do with the number of search results? It sounds to me like you want to remove something when a simple CSS change is all you need.

Comment: Removing the sidebar > more page space > change `products-grid products-grid--max-4-col first last odd` to `products-grid products-grid--max-6-col first last odd` = more products on a single page. I need `col-right sidebar` to be gone.

Comment: Are users not allowed to scroll down the page if there are more results than will fit on the screen?

Comment: Why would I want them to scroll down to view more products if I can remove unnecessary space like `col-right sidebar` so more products fit on a single page? That doesn't make any sense UX wise.

Comment: If that's all you want, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190678/how-to-change-product-view-page-to-one-column-layout  -- Otherwise it sounds like all you need is a CSS adjustment.

Comment: If you are a believer in "Above the fold" then yes, you're right. If you don't believe in "Above the fold", then you are over-complicating things. A quick Internet search on "above the fold myth" might be a worthwhile read for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the root template for `<catalog_category_default>` and `<catalog_category_layered>` inside your local.xml

i.e.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Notice `page/2columns-left.phtml`. The template you are using is `page/3columns.phtml`

Take a look inside `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/` for default layout templates that come with Magento.

Comment: It is better to edit the `catalog.xml` in this case, so you can set the correct template where it was intended to be defined - IMO

Answer (score 3):

app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml

line 33-35 change to:

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">
```